# Cannot upgrade Python

Tags: ubuntu, installation, python

I just recently tried using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to generate free SSL certs for a small website I'm running on a personal server. When I ran the `letsencrypt-auto` tool everything seemed to work, although a string of errors flew by in the console among which were `SNIMissingWarning` and `InsecurePlatformWarning`

Doing some research I found that both of these errors were likely related to my version of Python: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning

I tried using `apt-get` to upgrade Python but it only bumped me from 2.7.3 to 2.7.6 -- not far enough as I need 2.7.9

So I went to Python's website, downloaded the source, and ran `./configure`, `make`, and `make install`. Now I'm getting this strange behavior:

```
root@my-server:~# which python
/usr/local/bin/python
root@my-server:~# /usr/local/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.10
root@my-server:~# python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

Can someone explain this or tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the old python executable is still present.
This is not the real problem.
The one in /usr/local/bin/python should be the one you should be executing since it should override the one present in an over folder.

Try checking if you have a python executable in /usr/bin/
And why the overone is used.

Hope it is help you ...

Comment: Well, I think I know exactly what you're problem is.
If you follow the installation guide, and pass as a root user before make install.
Then when you go back to you're regular user, this one does not know this new version of python.
to do that you can do this :

```bash
sudo rm /usr/bin/python && sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/pyton
```

Don't worry, in case this does not work for you you can reverse it by doing this :

`sudo rm /usr/bin/python && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python`